# Password Validation Regular Expression - how to include special character?

Tags: objective-c, regex, passwords

```
@"^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$"
```

I am using this regular expression for password validation which gives one upper case, one lowercase and a number. But what I want is a special character in it but it should optional but above mentioned must be mandatory.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want *at least* or *exactly* one uppercase, lowercase, number, and special character. And what do you want to be optional? The existence of a special character?

Comment: can you point in the expression that checks the special character ?

Comment: What happens with that regex when you use a special character ? Does it allow ?

Comment: ? is a reserved character in regex

Comment: If you are just trying to see if certain characters are in a string, it might be simpler to not use regex. However if you are doing more than that regex would likely be better.

Comment: Obligatory link to this answer.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/25646

Comment: i want special character to be optional @Dopapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow these special characters: `-` (hyphen), `*` (asterisk) and `_` (underscore).

`^(?=[-_*]*)(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.[a-zA-Z]+.)[-*_0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$`

If you want to add your own special characters, add them into this part of the regex `[-*_0-9a-zA-Z]` (inside the square bracket)